# Scaling values with a known upper limit

Tags: excel, math, scale

I have a column of values in Excel that I need to modify by a scale factor. Original column example:

```
| Value |
|:-----:|
| 75    |
| 25    |
| 25    |
| 50    |
| 0     |
| 0     |
| 100   |
```

Scale factor: 1.5

```
| Value |
|:-----:|
| 112.5 |
| 37.5  |
| 37.5  |
| 75    |
| 0     |
| 0     |
| 150   |
```

The problem is I need them to be within a range of `0`-`100`. My first thought was take them as percentages of 100, but then quickly realized that this would be going in circles.

Is there some sort of mathematical method or Excel formula I could use to handle this so that I actually make meaningful changes to the values, such that when these numbers are modified, `150` is `100` but `37.5` might not be `25` and I'm not just canceling out my scale factor?

Comment: It would be very easy to distribute the numbers in a range from 0-100. Do you just want the ensure that 100 is the max value. Look at `min(100, cell * 1.5)`

Comment: @shawnt00 Well that might be what I'm looking for but I really felt like there should be a way to scale the numbers so that the largest number is 100, but then 90 might be more like 97 now. Do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: Yes, you could easily translate the max value to 100, then min to 0 and proportional differences between the rest.

Comment: @shawnt00 But wouldn't the proportional differences (which is exactly what I'm looking for) be the exact same values if the values are already set between a maximum of 0 and 100? It seems circular.

Comment: Yes, they would be the same in that scenario.

Comment: That's what I thought. I think the `MIN` formula has to be what I'm looking for (my boss is looking for) because everything else will be circular reasoning.

Comment: I'm sure you could find some other more complicated distribution model. Perhaps you want the values to cluster around 100 after multiple iterations?

Comment: Perhaps?: `=if(cell = 100, 100, 100 * (cell - min(<range>)) / (max(<range values less than 100>) - min(<range>)))`

Comment: Do you think you could post both the sample input and expected output of your data? You would need to show enough data to cover all edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data begin in cell A1, you can use this formula:

```
=MIN(100,A1*1.5)
```

Copy downward as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
ScaledValue = (v - MIN(AllValues)) / (MAX(AllValues) - MIN(AllValues)) * (SCALE_MAX - SCALE_MIN) + SCALE_MIN
```

Say your raw data (a.k.a. AllValues) ranges from a MIN of 15 to a MAX of 83, and you want to scale it to a range of 0 to 100. To do that you would set `SCALE_MIN = 0` and `SCALE_MAX = 100`. In the above equation, `v` is any single value in the data.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
ScaledValue = PERCENTRANK.INC(AllValues, v)
```

In contrast to my earlier suggestion, (linear --- preserves relative spacing of the data points), this preserves the order of the data but not spacing. Using `PERCENTRANK.INC` will have the effect that sparse data will get compressed closer together, and bunched data will get spread out.

You could also do a weighted combination of the two methods --- give the linear method a weight of say 0.5 so that relative spacing is *partially* preserved.